# how to restrict input type

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-directive

Currently I'm trying to restrict input data which can only input 3 letters and 2 numbers. It will be checked after onclicked button. My incorrect code:

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" name="test3" [(ngModel)]="test3" 
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\a-\z\A-\Z0-9]/g,'');">
<button (click)="checkNumber3(test3)">submit</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
checkNumber3(test3): void {
    console.log(test3);
    if (test3 !== test3.match(/([a-z])+/) * 2 || test3 !== test3.match(/([A-Z])+/) * 2
    && test3 !== test3.match(/([0-9])+/) * 3
    ) {
        alert('only can input 2 letters plus 3 numbers');
    } else {
        alert('correct');
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does it do wrong?

Comment: dude u mean my code or my post which edited by mr.pimpale?

Comment: Your code. He's asking how it misbehaves, how it ought to behave. Prashant's edits aren't visible yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript block needed some changes. Give this a shot:

```
if (test3.match(/([A-z])/g).length === 2 && (test3.match(/([0-9])/g).length === 3)) {
    alert('correct');
} else {
    alert('only can input 2 letters plus 3 numbers');
}
```

Comment: @seekerJackson glhf :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do somethig like:

```
if(test3.match(/([a-z])+/).length === 2 || 
   test3.match(/([A-Z])+/).length === 2 && 
   test3.match(/([0-9])+/).length === 3)
{
    doStuff()
}
```

EDIT (Explaination)

String.match returns an array of matches. So getting its length will let you know if you have correct data.

Also, the correct regex is `/([a-z]])/g` and analagically for `A-Z` and `0-9`

Comment: You can also simplify it to `test3.match(/([A-Za-z])/g).length === 2`

Comment: you are such a nice guy thank you very much and my problem fixed already <3

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running multiple RegExes over the same string and creating throw-away arrays. you should be able to make a simple validate functions with a single regex and `test()`. For example:

```js
function validate(string) {
  // two letters or three numbers
  return /^([a-zA-Z]{2}|[0-9]{3})$/.test(string)
}


console.log(validate("Aa"))   // true
console.log(validate("Aaa"))  // false
console.log(validate("120"))  // true
console.log(validate("1090")) // false
console.log(validate("1"))    // false
console.log(validate(""))     // false
console.log(validate("A3"))   // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [maxlength] and [minlength] is component.html file for checking the length.

and for checking number and letter in the ts file, use ^\d{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}$ this regex.

Comment: Good start, but write the actual code for more votes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `split()` and `filter()` like so:

```
checkNumber3(test3): void {
    console.log(test3);
    if (test3.split("").filter(e => isNaN(e)).length > 2 || test3.split("").filter(e => typeof parseInt(e) == "number")) {
        alert('only can input 2 letters plus 3 numbers');
    } else {
        alert('correct');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this!

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkIf_AlphaNum()
    {
            var regex1 = RegExp('^([a-zA-Z]){3}([0-9]){2}?$');
            if(regex1.test(document.getElementById("txtnumber").value)) 
            {
                document.getElementById("msg_2_show").innerHTML="given string matched against pattern!";
                document.getElementById("msg_2_show").style.color="#7CFC00";

                //alert("given string matched against pattern!");
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("msg_2_show").innerHTML="invalid  pattern!";
                document.getElementById("msg_2_show").style.color="#B22222";


                }
    }
</script>

</head>


<body>
<h4 id="msg_2_show"></h4>
<form   >
        <label>Enter No.:</label>

        <input type="text" id="txtnumber" name="txtnumber"  />
        <input type="button" value="Submit!" name="btnsubmit" onclick="checkIf_AlphaNum()"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add your checknumber function like below code inside input keypress

```js
<input type="text" name="test3" [(ngModel)]="test3"  (keypress)="checkNumber3(test3)"
onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\a-\z\A-\Z0-9]/g,'');">
<button (click)="checkNumber3(test3)">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it from here for **Angular 6** online editor :

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4wqkkk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)